# Select all fields from table and use with arcpy.DeleteIdentical_management()?

Tags: arcpy, table, loop, field-mapping, duplication

I would like to use `arcpy.DeleteIdentical_management()` function without having to specify all fields in the table.

Is there a keyword used to select all field in a table? I tried "*" or "ALL" but none worked.

Here is the code :

```
import os
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

table = "table1"
fields = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

arcpy.DeleteIdentical_management(table, fields)
```

Comment: You can get a list of fields like `fields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(table)]` You'll want to filter out OID, shape, GUID, etc.

Comment: I think that's weird there isn't another way of doing that but anyway it worked for me so thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

As [suggested](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238085/arcpy-deleteidentical-management-select-all-fields-in-the-table#comment371294_238085) by Paul, use `arcpy.ListFields()` to get a list of columns names from variable `table` and loop through it:

```
import os
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

table = "table1"
fields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(table)]

arcpy.DeleteIdentical_management(table, fields)
```